# activating only div subclasses on click with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a wordpress query looping through posts on a page. Each .audio-box has 2 .play buttons that I need to work together, when one is clicked I want the other one in that div to do the same. The problem is i have multiple audio-box divs on the page. I just need the 2 play buttons in that specific .audio-box div to work at the same time not all the others.

This is the html I have:

```
<div class="audio-box">

        <div class="audio-btn">
            <img src="image/path.jpg" alt="play" />
        </div>
        <div class="audio-content">
            <div class="date">Published 18/01/20</div>
            <h2>title</h2>
            <p>content</p>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        <div class="audio-player play-wrap">
            <audio id="player" class="music">
                <source src="path/to/audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
            </audio>

            <div id="audio-player">
                <div id="controls">
                    <i id="play" class="fa fa-play play"></i>
                    <div id="progressbar"></div>
                    <span id="time" class="time">00:00</span>
                    <i id="mute" class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>
                    <div id="volume"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <i class="fa fa-play play"></i>

        </div>


    </div>
```

This is the javascript that i have:

```
play_button.click(function() {
        player[player.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
        $('.play').toggleClass("fa-pause", !player.paused);
        $('.play').toggleClass("fa-play", player.paused);
    });
```

I know the issue is because I am saying toggle class on the .play element but is there any way to say that .play element within that specific .audio-box div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will look upward from the clicked button, to the next parent `.audio-box`
and will unfold the action on the `.play` elements it finds in it somewhere:

```
play_button.click(function() {
    player[player.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
    $(this).closest('.audio-box')
           .find('.play')
           .toggleClass("fa-pause", !player.paused)
           .toggleClass("fa-play", player.paused);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".audio-box").click(()=>{
    $(".audio-box").children().css({"color": "red", "border": "2px solid red"});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Aint you missing the selector in `$("audio-box")` ? either `.` or `#`

Comment: true, sorry I am fixing it

Comment: Also you should always leave a note about why your code solves the OP's problem. Also what your code does is that it sets all children of `.audio-box` color and border, how does that help?